# Finding derivative with respect to $x^2$

Tags: derivatives

I would like to find the derivative of $\frac{-n}{2x^2}(a^2+b)-(n) log(2x)$ with respect to $x^2$, where $a,b,n$ are constants.

My first instinct was to set $x^2=u$ and find the derivative of $\frac{-n}{2u}(a^2+b)-(n) log(2 \sqrt{u})$ with respect to $u$ and then plug back in $x^2=u$.

However, I do not think this is correct because it does not give me the answer I am looking for, am I missing chain rule or something similar?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{df}{du}\frac{du}{dx} $ where $\frac{du}{dx} = 2x$ and $f$ is the original expression you have

Comment: @SilviaRossi If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{df}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx} $$

And we have

$$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{n(a^2 + b - x^2)}{x^3}$$

$$\frac{du}{dx} = 2x$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but now I'm a little confused, I thought that I was trying to find $\frac{df}{du}$ using $\frac{df}{dx}/\frac{du}{dx}$?

Comment: @SilviaRossi Oops! You're absolutely right. I fixed my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Your method should work.

For example with respect to $u=x^2$ we have:

$$(x)’ = (\sqrt{u})’=\frac{1}{2 \cdot \sqrt{u}}=\frac{1}{2x}$$

However in these cases the use of chain rule is recommended.